# Get RStudio Server open source edition to use alternative gcc version

Tags: r, rstudio-server

I have the open source edition of RStudio Server installed on a RHEL7 machine. Since I need to install R packages that requires a more recent version of gcc/g++ than the one provided (4.8.5) I've installed 5.3.1 via Red Hat Developer Toolset.

I am, hovever, unable to get RStudio Server to use the newer gcc version. I've tried to append `source scl_source enable devtoolset-4` to the end of my .bash_profile as well as setting the `CC, CXX` and `COLLECT_LTD_WRAPPER` env. variables in the Makevars file in my home directory as well as in $R_HOME/etc/Renviron.site file. Running `system("gcc -v")` in RStudio Server still says that the gcc version is 4.8.5. However, if ssh into the server and run R from there and then check the gcc version it uses the correct one (5.3.1).

How do I get the R session in RStudio Server to use the more recent GCC version?

Comment: What is the output of `system("R CMD config CC")`? That's the compiler R will use by default. BTW, it is generally safest to first compile R with the compiler you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

Put your `PATH` var containing the gcc bin for the new version in `$R_HOME/etc/Renviron.site`
Something like this..

`PATH=/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin:/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin`

This is then globally set

You can also set it per session in R-studio

`Sys.setenv("PATH"="/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin:/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin")`

Answer (score 0):

Install devtoolset.

```sh
yum install centos-release-scl
yum install devtoolset-8-gcc devtoolset-8-gcc-c++
```

Add the following content to `~/.R/Makevars`.

```sh
CC=/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin/gcc
CXX=/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin/g++ -std=c++11
CXX11=/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin/g++ -std=c++11
CXX14=/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin/g++ -std=c++1y
CXX14FLAGS=-O3 -march=native -mtune=native -fPIC
```